# how can i install gevent on python 3.5.x virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gevent

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install gevent on python 3.5.x.

My initial research said its only in a stable release for 2.7?

I've been trying `pip install greenlet` but i get:

```
venv/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you install it directly on the site-package folder at `C:/PythonXX/Lib/site-packages` ?

Comment: i cant find the source

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have pip installed in your virtual environment. You can install it by activating virtual environment and running `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`